# Error message of broken packages while tryIng to install R on Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install R by trying the following command on Ubuntu 18.04x64:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install r-base
```

following [this tutorial (step 6)](https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/)

but I get :

[image]

I tried to solve it with :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496788/you-have-held-broken-package-while-trying-to-install-r) but I still take the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should post  responses from those commands when doing them one at a time.

Comment: Did you add `http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial` to your sources? Because if you're on Ubuntu 18.04 it should be `http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic` instead.

Comment: I get the same error by using this process https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: So which is it? Are you using 16.04 or 18.04?

Comment: I use 18.04. The result is the same

Comment: Exactly the same? Word for word and letter for letter? That would be rather strange. You should post the entire console output.